# Zagg Keyboard (enter key)

Tags: ipad

I have a Zagg Keyboard. For a while, it worked fine when I used Messenger. I think the problem came along when I updated the software. The issue is before the update the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key moved the cursor down a line. Now the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key sends the message. I can't stand this and want it back like it was before. Any ideas???

Answer (score 1):

This behaviour is up to the app/website to decide, so unfortunately you cannot change it back yourself. However, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> is a common shortcut on Mac and iOS to insert a linebreak when <kbd>Enter</kbd> normally submits.

Comment: Shift+Enter works for me too

Comment: I have tried both ways and it still send text message. Very frustrating.

Comment: Perhaps report this as a bug in Messenger to Facebook.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind I am using iOS 15.0.2 & using Messages for Android on Chrome. Use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> and it will work.